# REGEX email matching

Tags: regex

I have a JAVA string that is being used to validate proper email addresses.

```
^[\\w'-]+(\\.[\\w'-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+([.-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$
```

I want to user to be able to leave the address blank and not get an error message.  How is this possible?

Comment: Just make a condition for that. Its easier than reconfiguring the whole regular expression.

Comment: What programming language are you using? There may be a better solution than regex. Email addresses aren't easy to parse using a regex, but many languages have fairly standard functions for validating email addresses. For example, in PHP, you can simply use `filter_var()`; no regex required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any other code or specify what language you were using, the best I can suggest is:

```
(?:^[\\w'-]+(\\.[\\w'-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+([.-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$)|(?:^$)
```

Which will match an e-mail or an empty string.

Comment: This will only match email adresses not containing non-english characters

Comment: @migg This was the OP's regex, not mine. I just added the check for the empty string.

Comment: Sorry about that, new to the forum.  Using Java

Answer (score 0):

If you have an expression you want to make optional allowing empty string to match you could use any of the following:

```
^(?:regex)?\z
^\z|^regex\z
```